# Having troubles with removing and reapearing html elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to slide down a element, then when the button is hit again I want it to slide up, empty the div, then slide down with the new results. I'v been trying to figure out how to do this for so long and I cant seem to get it working with jquery.

```
$(".search").on("click",function(){
    $('.results').slideUp(500).empty().append("<p>Results</p>").hide().slideDown(500)
});
```

I understand this is kind of specific to my project kind of but I do feel others might find this useful

Comment: Simplify your problem, there is a lot of redundant codes

Comment: ... You do realize the word is "I've", right? There's no English word "Iv". Also, you say you "cant [sic] seem to get it working with jquery". What is happening that makes you say it's not working? Currently, you're assigning an click event handler on every iteration of the for loop, which I'm assuming you don't want...

Comment: Ok, I can see how confusing my question may seem when I'm rereading it over, I will fix some stuff really quick and make it a lot simpler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly your problem is, but I think the slideUp animation is not shown in your example.

The slideUp method takes a second argument, which is the function callback. It is called when the slideUp action is finished. If you do the rest of your actions in this callback function, is guaranteed to be performed after the slideUp.

```
jQuery('#testbutton').on('click',function() {
  $('#testlist').slideUp(500, function() {
    $('#testlist').empty().append("<li>this is a test</li>").slideDown(500);
  });  
});
```

You can find a fully working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dxyybwyh/5/

Answer (score 1):

> I want to slide down a element, then when the button is hit again I
>   want it to slide up, empty the div, then slide down with the new
>   results.

It seems simple enough to me

let me know if you need anything more

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
  if ( $( ".myDiv" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    //show the div
    $( ".myDiv" ).slideDown( "slow" );
    //add content
    $( ".myDiv" ).html("New Content")
  } else {
    //hide the div
    $( ".myDiv" ).slideUp( "slow" );
    //clear content
    $( ".myDiv" ).html("");

  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/Rohithzr/pen/jqmGXg

Updated the pen with append ability and more readability

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
  if ( $( ".myDiv" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    show();
  } else {
    hide();
    clearContent();
    appendContent("New Content");
  }
});
function clearContent(){
  //clear content
  $( ".myDiv" ).html("");
}
function appendContent(content){
  $( ".myDiv" ).html($( ".myDiv" ).html()+content);
}
function hide(){
  //hide the div
  $( ".myDiv" ).slideUp( "slow" );
}
function show(){
  //show the div
  $( ".myDiv" ).slideDown( "slow" );
}
```

Comment: The one problem I have with this solution is that the new contant appends during slideUp. You should be using the callback Mechanism to determine when to fire clear and append.

Comment: well yes you can simply use the callback function as stated by @kogelnikp above ... sorry i was away hence couldnot see your comment earlier